# adding date and time to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL field that is `DATETIME` ... I have a PHP page that generates a query that will add some data in a table which includes teh `DATETIME` field.

The question is, how can I add the `DATETIME` from PHP to MySQL?

I want to add the time in GMT/UTC 24H format

Comment: This might be far too Googleable...

Comment: @KyleMacey: I've been on Google for around an hour!! If you know how to do it, then help.

Comment: @sikas, you didn't look too hard. Your question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947184/inserting-a-date-and-time-value-to-a-mysql-from-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$current_time = date ('Y-m-d h:m');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql> create table t1 (id int, blah datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values (1, '2008-01-01 12:32');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t1;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | blah                |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2008-01-01 12:32:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hasan, I'm seeking to do this from PHP ... Get Current time and date and add it to the database

Comment: Hasan's point was that you need to format the `datetime` string in the same form as how he input it: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = date ('Y-m-d h:m');
```

Then insert $time into your mysql table

see http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php for more info